# sysarticles system view - what does a status of 57 mean?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm trying to work out why one article within a publication isn't replicating. I've scripted it out and confirmed the replication procs it's supposed to call are the correct ones, and have run a trace on the destination instance looking for those procs being called - no results.

Querying the sysarticles view in the published database, I noticed the article in question has a status of 57, whereas the rest of the articles have a status of 17.

Looking at msdb, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174970(v=sql.90).aspx, there are 5 bitwise values available: 1, 8, 16, 24, 64.

So it makes sense that the articles with status 17 are made up of 1 and 16 above.

But even if I add all bitwise values above excluding 64, I can't get a status value of 57. The max is 49.

Can anyone please explain to me what a status of 57 is, and whether it could be the cause of my article not replicating.

Thankfully this isn't on production, so I'm going to try and update the status manually, and if that doesn't work, take the table out of replication and add it again as its own publication.

But it would be good to understand what a status of 57 means.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what that status value means, but most of my articles are listed with status 57 and they are working just fine.

I'm guessing that there's a bitwise value of 32 which is missing (why else go from 16 to 64) and I'm guessing that 24 should actually be 32 as 24 isn't a valid bitwise value.

```
57 = 1+8+16+32
```

I'll see if I can get it confirmed that the 24 should actually be 32.

Comment: If you read the description of 8, 16, and 24, it is clear that 24 is meant to be a combination of 8 and 16.  I think the description is simply redundant

Comment: True, the description of 24 does make it look like a combination of 8 and 16. I've got an email into the product group to see what the value of 32 should be. Hopefully they'll get back to me shortly.

Comment: I am definitely interested in what they say.  I have a process that scripts out our replication environment for DR reasons, and have always just included the 32 bit in the bitmask, as all of my articles contain it.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yea, makes sense there's a missing 32 bit value. I ended up taking that article out of the publication and setting up a new one and it's working. I also checked prod (should've done it earlier!) and that article is status 57 and replicating fine.

Comment: 13 years later and Microsoft is still not defining what 32 means.  Interesting...